# App uploading problem with xcode 4.

Tags: iphone, xcode4, submission

I am trying to upload an app through the xcode 4 archive organizer. Whenever I try to validate or submit I enter in my itunes connect credentials but on the next window it asks for an application record and I get "No Value".

I have an app that is "waiting for upload" on itunes connect and I've made sure my login information is correct. I have no idea what else to try. Please help!

Here is a link to the exact problem I am having on the apple developer forums: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/95610?tstart=0
No one has posted an answer there either. =/

Edit: I ended up downloading application loader and doing it the old fashion xcode3 way and it worked just fine. I don't know why it stopped working in xcode4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds a bit strange, I have 10 apps in the iTunes store.  We are going to need some more information?  If it says "prepare for upload" then you still have to login to iTunes Connect and navigate to that screen.  You will notice that on the top right of this screen you should see a blue blue button saying "ready to upload binary". Click that unless you have already. But I suspect you have missed this step?

Hmmm, I just did that for one of my apps and then is says "waiting for upload" ok.  Not sure now.  In xCode have you got all you provisioning profiles installed and the iTunes WWDC (or what ever it is called) certificate installed?

Comment: I think the problem was that I didnt have that WWDR certificate that you were talking about. But now I am getting this when I try and Archive the app: Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1. I'm looking around and trying to figure this one out. Btw I am running xcode 4.0.2

Comment: That does sound like a certificate issue.  You may need to recreate all the certificates from scratch, starting with the developer cert, then the distribution certificate, and so on. iTunes connect has good documentation you should review for all the parts required.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using XCode 4.2?  You cannot submit to the app store with it; you must use 4.1 (on Lion) or 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

We were having the same problem and were using Xcode 4.2. We solved the problem by removing Xcode completely, moving everything in the Developer folder into the trash. Then we downloaded and installed the latest build of Xcode 4.2 via the Mac App Store. The problem was probably due to using an earlier build of Xcode or inconsistencies in Xcode from having upgraded from earlier versions over the years.